# How to run PowerShell script by Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, ssms

I'm new with SSMS and PowerShell and I need some hint. I'm working with SSRS and handling schedulation by SSMS. In particular I'm going to generate a report by SSRS and, when the report has been generated I must send it by mail through a SSMS by a powershell script. So the first step of schedulation is to generate the report. As step two my script must get data from query, wait till report has been generated and then send the report. The point that block my script (no error.. just keep waiting also if the file exists) is that:

```
while ($True) 
{ 
   if (Test-Path($PathComplete)) 
   {
      break 
   }
   Start-Sleep -s 3 
}
```

And if I remove this piece of code the script works well (if the file exists).

All the script works well in PowerShell run by cmd

Someone can help me?

Tnx too much

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest using a endless while but if you have to

```
while (!(Test-Path($PathComplete))) 
{ 

   Start-Sleep -s 3 
}
```

**!(Test-Path())** means if Test-path returns $false

Comment: Nothing.. The code keep to be blocked at the same point.. I think that the problem is the line
Start-Sleep -s 3

Comment: how do you know its not that the fact test-path is coming back false

Comment: I tried the same script on PowerShell run by cmd and the script works well. If I remove the report the script wait and if I put the report in the directory the script move on till the end. 
At the same condition, PowerShell in SSMS keep waiting..

Comment: So you saying when you remove Start-Sleep -s 3 from that while statement then it works correctly?

Comment: Well I tried right now and all the while (!(Test-Path(....))) {} block the esecution...

Comment: So it didnt work even when you took away the Start-sleep....if thats so then Start-Sleep isnt the issue and the endless loop you have is the issue. Test-Path is coming back false